# Is it possible for applications in different MobileFirst projects to engage in SSO?

Tags: security, single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst Platform [has a single sign-on (SSO) feature](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_configuring_device_SSO.html?lang=en) which enables users logged on in one application to be automatically logged in another. The SSO feature is enabled through the `authenticationConfig.xml` file, on a specific login module, so logically this is within the domain of one MobileFirst runtime/project.

Is it possible to enable SSO that works between applications in separate runtimes/projects, or is it limited to apps only within the one runtime/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSO feature is limited to applications of the same project.